# How to search for the Nth (2nd, 3rd, etc.) white space in a paragraph?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

How to search (via GREP) for the Nth (2nd, 3rd, etc.) white space in a paragraph in Adobe Indesign?

Comment: Don't think you can, GREP is not a programming language. Might be possible with scripting however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

#### Find what

`(([^\s]*\s?){n})\s(.*\r)` where `n` is a number of your choice.

#### Change to

`$1text$3` where `text` is the text you want to change the nth space to.

---

### Explanation

#### Find what

```
(           // begin parenthesis 1
  (         // begin parenthesis 2
    [^\s]*  // find zero or more non white spaces
    \s?     // followed by zero or one white space
  )         // end parenthesis 2 (assign the parenthesis to $2 - not used)
  {n}       // repeat everything in parenthesis 2 "n" times ("n" must be a number)
)           // end parenthesis 1 (assign the parenthesis to $1)
\s          // followed by a white space (the one we are looking for)
(           // begin parenthesis 3
  .*        // followed by zero or more characters
  \r        // followed by end of paragraph
)           // end parenthesis 3 (assign the parenthesis to $3)
```

#### Change to

```
$1          // keep everything from parenthesis 1 (before the wanted white space)
text        // change the found white space to "text" of your choice
$3          // keep everything from parenthesis 3 (after the wanted white space)
```